# Updating OS on protected machine

Tags: macos, software-update

I work offsite and for a large company and need my OS updated. The tech support has been outsourced and it's impossible to get anything done if you work offsite. Whenever I try and update OS through the app store it is blocked.

Is there a way to update to Yosemite without going through the app store? 
I have admin access but there is something protecting the computer from accessing the OS update. My problem is, ADOBE CC 15 requires a new OS which I can't install... so I'm stuck in CC14 while all my vendors have upgraded.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there any non-protected Macs you have access to? (No, my answer isn't going to be "use that instead," but the solution I have in mind requires a Mac than can access the App Store.)

Answer (score 1):

- You can download the installer on any other Mac.
- You may or may not be able to run the installer from your modified OS
- You can always run a second OS on your Mac unless there is a firmware password too

Most management tools that can block the OTA install have also blocked he installer from running. The installer is trivial to block, the download much harder.

Worst case, boot to Internet recovery and just install Yosemite on to a SD card or USB drive and migrate the data you need.

That way, you still have the OS that is officially supported, but also an OS to run the tools you've decided you need. Don't write off IT - they may have a group for people that insist on the newest OS and use them for testing.